# nyagosの組み込みコマンドのlsで表示されるパーミッションの意味

Tags: untagged

`nyagos`の組み込みコマンドの`ls`で表示されるパーミッションの解説はどこかで見れますか？

```
$ ls -l
drwxa--    0 Feb  5 21:34:21 archetypes/
-rw-a-- 5.9K Feb 11 07:29:45 config.toml
drwxa--    0 Feb  4 06:10:10 content/
```

`drwx`の意味はわかるのですが、`a`および、表示のない残り2つの項目はどういう意味を持つのか[ドキュメント](https://github.com/zetamatta/nyagos/blob/master/Doc/04-Commands_ja.md)を参照しましたがわかりませんでした。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

開発者です。すみません、書くのを忘れておりました。

各フラグをすべて記すと `drwxash` になります。`ash` の部分は MS-DOS由来のファイル属性です。それぞれ

- `a` … アーカイブ属性
- `s` … システム ファイル属性
- `h` … 隠しファイル属性

になります。隠しファイル属性のファイルはただの `ls -l` では表示されないので、`ls -al` のように `-a` オプションをつける必要があります。たいていの環境では `ls -al C:\` とすると、システム属性や隠しファイル属性のファイルがいくつか確認できると思います。

今後ともよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。 `ls -la c:\`で各属性が確認できました。アーカイブ属性については存在さえ知らなかったので勉強になりました。